# How to edit a property of a object on an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array in a useState.
and I want to edit a property.

```
const [equipe_montador, setEquipe_Montador] = useState([]);

<Card title="Adicionar Mão de Obra">
        {equipe_montador.map((item, key) =>
            <div key={key}>
                <InputBox type="number" maxLength={6} title={item.nome} value={item.quantidade} onChange={e => setEquipe_Montador([...equipe_montador, { ...item, quantidade: e.target.value }])} />
            </div>
        )}
    </Card>
```

But, when I edit the value, the item duplicate.

Comment: Try `setEquipe_Montador(equipe_montador.map((o) => o === (item ? ({ ...item, quantidade: e.target.value }) : o)))`

Comment: Show us an example of the array data

Comment: It's an array using  this structure:
{
 {
  id: '1', 
  id_objeto: '1', 
  nome: 'Encarregado',
  ativo: 'False',
  quantidade: '222'
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the solution.
It's working, but I don't know if is the best approach.
I edit the object and create a new list with the edited object.

```
        <Card title="Adicionar Mão de Obra">
        {equipe_montador.map((item, key) =>
            <div key={key}>
                <InputBox type="number" maxLength={6} title={item.nome} value={item.quantidade} onChange={e => {
                    var new_array = equipe_montador.map((new_obj) => new_obj.id_objeto === item.id_objeto ?
                        {
                            ...new_obj,
                            quantidade: e.target.value
                        } : new_obj);
                    setEquipe_Montador(new_array);
                }
                } />
            </div>
        )}
    </Card>
```